# URL parameters when running PHP via CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is there any way I can pass parameters (like Query string in URL, or URL parameters) to a PHP file which is being run via CLI? I need this for some PHP cron jobs which need input from parameters. For example:

```
$ php /home/abc/www/myphp.php?param1=abc
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) and especially [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two special variables in every command line interface `argc` and `argv`.

`argv` - array of arguments passed to the script.

`argc` - the number of command line parameters passed to the script (if run on the command line).

Make script cli.php

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER['argv']);
```

and call it with argument:

```
$ php cli.php argument1=1
```

You should get the output looking like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cli.php
    [1] => argument1=1
)
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

If you are still so demanding to have a single point entry and to be able to process the url query as $_GET make your script act like a router by adding a switch:

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
   // ... BUILD $_GET array from argv[0] 
}
```

But then - it violates SRP - Single Responsibility Principle! Having that in mind if you're still so demanding to make it work like you stated in the question you can do it like:

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
   /** ... BUILD  from argv[0], by parsing the query string, a new array and 
    *  name it $data or at will 
    */
}
else
{
   // ... BUILD  new $data array from $_GET array
}
```

After that convert the code to use $data array instead of $_GET

...and have a nice day!

Comment: This is not very useful for running a script intended to take query string parameters on the CLI...

Comment: @aderuwe, IMHO, it is very useful. You can take argv[0] explode it and build $_GET array by hand, also if you're running a scipt thru cli and expect it to behave like it's running from the request it violates SRP - Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Well, you didn't actually explain the building $_GET part. Agree with the second part of your comment.

Comment: @aderuwe i did it on purpose. ;) but anyway thanks, i'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

If the underlying code absolutely requires `$_GET` (and does not rely on other HTTP features) you can write a simple wrapper that abuses the fact that isn't a read-only superglobal:

```
<?php
// Untested (tweak to your own needs)
foreach($argv as $i){
    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $i, 2);
    $_GET[$k] = $v;
}
require_once('/home/abc/www/myphp.php');
```

... and then schedule your proxy instead:

```
php /path/to/wrapper.php param1=abc
```

Comment: I think you mean 'foreach' - other than that, upvoted.

Comment: Clever solution. I used a for to skip the first 'argv' which is the 'wrapper.php' itself: "for ($n = 1; $n < $argc; $n++) list($k, $v) = explode('=', $argv[$n], 2);"

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extracted/rewritten class from my CLI Application library using `$_SERVER['argv']` in the same form that linux runs commands (`foo.sh --param "value" --marap`):

```
<?php
    class ArgumentScanner {
        private static $instance;
        private $arguments;

        public static function get() {
            if (empty(self::$instance)) {
                self::$instance = new ArgumentScanner();
            }

            return self::$instance;
        }

        public function __construct() {
            $this->arguments = $this->parseArguments($_SERVER['argv']);
        }

        public function __isset($argument) {
            return isset($this->arguments[$argument]);
        }

        public function __get($argument) {
            return (isset($this->arguments[$argument]) ? $this->arguments[$argument] : null);
        }

        /**
         * Is used to parse the contents of $_SERVER['argv']
         * @param array $argumentsRaw The arguments from $_SERVER['argv']
         * @return stdClass An object of properties in key-value pairs
         */
        private function parseArguments($argumentsRaw) {
            $argumentBuffer = '';
            foreach ($argumentsRaw as $argument) {
                if ($argument[0] == '-') {
                    $argumentBuffer = substr($argument, ($argument[1] == '-' ? 2 : 1));
                    $equalSign = strpos($argumentBuffer, '=');
                    if ($equalSign !== false) {
                        $argumentKey = substr($argumentBuffer, 0, $equalSign);
                        $argumentsParsed[$argumentKey] = substr($argumentBuffer, $equalSign + 1);
                        $argumentBuffer = '';
                    } else {
                        $argumentKey = $argumentBuffer;
                        $argumentsParsed[$argumentKey] = '';
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($argumentBuffer != '') {
                        $argumentKey = $argumentBuffer;
                        $argumentsParsed[$argumentKey] = $argument;
                        $argumentBuffer = '';
                    }
                }
            }
            return (object)$argumentsParsed;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Use**:

```
<?php
    $argumentScanner = ArgumentScanner::get();

    if (isset($argumentScanner->reset)) {
        echo '--reset was passed!';
    }

    if (isset($argumentScanner->test)) {
        echo '--test was passed as ' . $argumentScanner->test . '!';
    }

    if (isset($argumentScanner->foo)) {
        echo '--foo was passed as ' . $argumentScanner->foo . '!';
    }

    if (isset($argumentScanner->bar)) {
        echo '--bar was passed as ' . $argumentScanner->bar . '!';
    }
?>

php script.php --foo "bar" --reset -test="hey you!"
```

**Output**:

> --reset was passed!
>   --test was passed as hey you!
>   --foo was passed as bar!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution there would be to refactor and abstract away the business logic, retain the original script as a wrapper for it. Then add a CLI script to wrap the same business logic for the CLI.
That way, you can use the normal CLI parameter handling: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing, pass query parameters to a php script to run as a cron job.  The script was from a third party and I didn't want to modify or write a new script.  The solution was to place the query string parameters in single quotes and replace the question mark with an ampersand. In my case, I pass three parameters.

```
php /home/abc/www/myphp.php '&param1=abc&param2=def&param3=123'
```

I found the solution in this [post](https://thatlinuxbox.com/blog/article.php/php-cli-query-parameters), tried it and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
    parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
}
```

This is solution that I use, if running via cli, put vars and values in $_GET,
seems that is working for simple tasks , not sure if work with php getopt etc

Answer (score -1):

try wget and output to null

```
wget http://localhost/myphp.php?param1=abc -o /dev/null
```

Comment: Very creative, but this activates at least 2 php processes and other processes on the server (apache, nginx, caddy, tomcat, etc.), so this is an irrational solution.